# SQL queries with slight modification giving different results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am learning SQL and doing some exercise with analytics functions. I have following query to find out `ship_name` and `order_value` of the highest placed order. Following are my tables:

```
orders(id, ship_name, city_of_origination)
order_details(id, order_id, unit_price, quantity)
```

In order to solve this problem, I wrote following query:

```
select o.ship_name, od.quantity*od.unit_price, first_value(od.quantity*od.unit_price) over (order by od.quantity*od.unit_price desc)
from orders o
inner join order_details od
on o.order_id = od.order_id
limit 1
```

Here id the sample output after removing `limit` in above query:

[image: Result of above query]

Changing the problem statement slightly, I only want the ship_name. So I wrote this query:

```
select tmp.ship_name
from (select o.ship_name as ship_name, first_value(od.quantity*od.unit_price) over (order by od.quantity*od.unit_price desc) fv 
      from orders o
     inner join order_details od
      on o.order_id = od.order_id
      limit 1
     ) tmp;
```

To my surprise, the result changed. Here is the result of above wuery without `limit`:
[image: Result of above query]

At the same time, if I execute following query:

```
select tmp.ship_name, tmp.fv
from (select o.ship_name as ship_name, first_value(od.quantity*od.unit_price) over (order by od.quantity*od.unit_price desc) fv 
      from orders o
     inner join order_details od
      on o.order_id = od.order_id
      limit 1
     ) tmp;
```

I get the same result (and the expected one) as that of the first query. My question is: Why is there a difference of results in above queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`limit` without `order by` returns an arbitrary row.  It might not even return the same row for the same query when executed subsequent times.

So, use `order by` to control *which* row is returned.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, row order is returned based on the hidden column `ctid` order.  Essentially, it's last-updated/last-inserted order--it just orders based on the order it finds it on-disk.  Using `LIMIT` does not change that order, as it's still going to come out in the order that it's read out of the disk.

Using `LIMIT 1` will only show you the first row it encounters off disk.  To change the ordering behavior, you should use `ORDER BY`